# How to enable htmlmixed mode by codemirror?

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

I want the mode htmlmixed in codemirror.  I start searching in the codemirror API but i cannot find it.  I included the following:

```
<script src="cm/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cm/lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="cm/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
```

And this is my code:

```
MCM = CodeMirror(JY.get("devroot"), {
    mode:  "htmlmixed",
    value: "<p>Hello</p>"
});
```

But it doesn't work.  Does somebody know this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must also include the mode scripts `cm/mode/xml/xml.js`, `cm/mode/javascript/javascript.js`, and `cm/mode/css/css.js`, which are dependencies of the htmlmixed mode.

Comment: tks, script tag for htmlmixed only wont work

Answer (score 5):

@Marjin gave the correct answer. But the full code will look like this:

```
<script src="/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/js/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="/js/codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="/js/codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="/js/codemirror/mode/css/css.js"></script>
<script src="/js/codemirror/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>

<div class="page-wrap-editor">
    <h3 class="editor-head">HTML код</h3>
    <textarea id="ta"></textarea>
</div>


<script>
    const ta = document.getElementById(`ta`);
    const editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(ta, {
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode:  "htmlmixed",
        value: "<p>Hello</p>"
    });
</script>
```